# Is it possible to run the the same ecs task definition container twice on the same instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am attempting to run multiple tasks at the same time on the same EC2 instance within ECS. Each task has the same container but will be provided different overrides to internally launch different commands on the host.

Currently, the first task will run fine but the second gets stuck in a provisioning state until the first one finishes.

The host has 4 vCPUs and 16GB RAM. Both the task definition and the container have been assigned to reserve 2 vCPU and 8GB RAM (See Below)

```js
const taskDefinition = new TaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDefinition', {
    compatibility: Compatibility.EC2,
    memoryMiB: '8192',
    cpu: '2048',
})

const container = taskDefinition.addContainer('VideoSplicingContainer', {
    ...
    cpu: 2048,
    memoryLimitMiB: 8192,
    memoryReservationMiB: 8192,
    ...
})
```

Comment: Try with less ram and cpu for the tasks. Your instance still needs come cpu and ram for its own use. You can't just allocate 100% for tasks.

Comment: That did it thank you. If you answer the question, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments. If an instance has 4 vCPUs and 16GB RAM, it can't accommodate two tasks of 2 vCPU and 8GB RAM. This is because, not 100% available on the instance is allocated to the ECS tasks. The instance itself require some CPU and RAM to operate its own processes, e.g. docker.

Thus, you have to reduce the CPU and RAM use by the tasks.